# jQuery autocomplete enter key to a url

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

Trying to get the dropdown suggestions to go to a specified url when the enter key is pressed. I've tried creating a function that can read the address, but I'm stuck! Any help is appreciated!

```
function isNumberKey(evt){
  var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode
  if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))
    return false;
  return true;
}

$.widget( "custom.catcomplete", $.ui.autocomplete, {
    _renderMenu: function( ul, items ) {
      var that = this,
        currentCategory = "";
      $.each( items, function( index, item ) {
        if ( item.category != currentCategory ) {
          ul.append( "<li><a href=" + item.address + ">" + item.category + "</a></li>" );
          currentCategory = item.category;
        }        //that._renderItemData( ul, item );
      });
    }
  });

 var data=[
 { label: "96710", category: "Site 2", address: "http://www.test.com/site2" },
 { label: "96718", category: "Site 2", address: "http://www.test.com/site2" },
 { label: "96720", category: "Site 2", address: "http://www.test.com/site2" },
 { label: "96719", category: "Site 1", address: "http://www.test.com/site1" },
 { label: "96725", category: "Site 1", address: "http://www.test.com/site1" },   
 { label: "96814", category: "Site 3", address: "http://www.test.com/site3" },
 { label: "96815", category: "Site 3", address: "http://www.test.com/site3" }    
];

$(".auto").catcomplete({
  source: data,
  minLength: 1,
  autofocus: true,
});
```

Here's a test: https://jsfiddle.net/oey5vfg0/

Answer (score 0):

Open the console I found the issues when you type the first character.
Note to you:

- Any jQuery commands should be put in `callback` of `$(document).ready(callback)` to ensure html, css are loaded before trigger javascript/jQuery.
- No need to have `onkeypress="isNumberKey(event)"`, you should bind event with jQuery.

After fix two points above, I have this: https://jsfiddle.net/oey5vfg0/3/
I can search by `label` (eg: 96790). Now just fix the render part.

Comment: Thanks! I've fixed those two items. The next part I'm stuck at is the render part. When i do a search (eg: 96790) and I get my suggestion drop down, I want to use the down arrow key to select an item and hit enter to take me to the corresponding url. is that possible?

Comment: Figured it out! Thanks for the help!

Comment: you're welcome :)! Happy to know that I can help @BT